# BigQuery Data Transfer Service benchmarks for Campaign Manager data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, double-click-advertising

There's some good [info](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/transferring-big-data-sets-to-gcp) here on general transfer times over the wire for data to/from various sources.

Besides the raw data transfer time, I am trying to estimate roughly how long it would take to import ~12TB/day into BigQuery using the BigQuery Data Transfer service for [DoubleClick Campaign Manager](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/doubleclick-campaign-transfer).

Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

In the first link you've shared, there's an [image](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/transferring-big-data-sets-to-gcp#close) that shows the transfer speed (estimated) depending on the network bandwidth.

[image]

So let's say you have a bandwith of 1Gbps, then the data will be available in your GCP project in ~30 hours as you are transfering 12TB which is close to 10TB. That makes it 1 day and a half to transfer.

If you really want to transfer 12TB/day because you need that data to be available each day, and increasing bandwidth is not a possibility, I would recommend you to batch data and create different transfer services for each batch. As an example:

- Split 12TB into 12 batches of 1TB -> 12 transfer jobs of 1TB each
- Each batch will take 3 hours to complete, therefore you will have available 8/12TB a day.

This can be applied to smaller batches of data if you want to have a more fine-grained solution.